# Skyrim Requiem mod load order

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I run Tes5Edit I get two errors about Moonpath_questdata.esp and Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp and their Requiem patches.

Should I just move Requiem and all Requiem patches at the bottom just before bashed patch?

Is the rest of the load order ok?

Please make suggestions as to what I should do to minimize conflicts if any. Requiem is the heart of my mod list, so I wouldn't mind if I had to remove some mods in favor of stability/compatibility.

Is it safe to use Predator Vision mod with Requiem?

So here is my mod load order, sorted out by boss:

```
Skyrim.esm=1
Update.esm=1
Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp=1
Dawnguard.esm=1
Unofficial Dawnguard Patch.esp=1
HearthFires.esm=1
Unofficial Hearthfire Patch.esp=1
Dragonborn.esm=1
Unofficial Dragonborn Patch.esp=1
Skyrim Project Optimization - Full Version.esm=1
ClimatesOfTamriel.esm=1
moonpath.esm=1
SPIKE.esm=1
HighResTexturePack01.esp=1
HighResTexturePack02.esp=1
HighResTexturePack03.esp=1
Unofficial High Resolution Patch.esp=1
Chesko_Frostfall.esp=1
AOS.esp=1
Improved Combat Sounds v2.2.esp=1
AOS_ICS Patch.esp=1
Thundering Shouts.esp=1
mintylightningmod.esp=1
MintyLightningMod_COT_Patch.esp=1
fantasy music overhaul.esp=1
StaticMeshImprovementMod.esp=1
StaticMeshImprovementMod-DragonbornTernFix.esp=1
StaticMeshImprovementMod-FurnitureChestSnowFix.esp=1
Better Skill and Quest Books Names.esp=1
Chesko_WearableLantern.esp=1
CookingExpanded.esp=1
CookingExpanded - Hearthfire.esp=1
CookingExpanded - Dragonborn.esp=1
Dead Body Collision.esp=1
ORM-Arvak.esp=1
Realistic Wildlife Loot - Reduced.esp=1
SkyUI.esp=1
Cloaks.esp=1
Cloaks - Dawnguard.esp=1
LeftHandRings.esp=1
LeftHandRings - Dawnguard.esp=1
Requiem.esp=1
Requiem - Resources.esp=1
Requiem - Hard Times.esp=1
Requiem - HearthFires.esp=1
Requiem - Dragonborn.esp=1
Requiem - Moonpath Patch.esp=1
Requiem - Guard Dialogue Overhaul Patch.esp=1
AOS_Requiem Patch.esp=1
moonpath_questdata.esp=1
BlockSparkles.esp=1
AOS_BlockSparkles Patch.esp=1
Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp=1
TravelMounts.esp=1
Drinking Fountains of Skyrim.esp=1
EnhancedLightsandFX.esp=1
ELFX - Exteriors.esp=1
ELFX - Moonpath.esp=1
ELFX - Dawnguard.esp=1
ELFX - Dragonborn.esp=1
ClimatesOfTamriel-Dawnguard-Patch.esp=1
ClimatesOfTamriel-Dragonborn-Patch.esp=1
AOS_CoT 3.1 compatibility patch.esp=1
ClimatesOfTamriel-Nights-Level-5.esp=1
prod80_CoT_patch.esp=1
Supreme Storms - Cot Version.esp=1
prod80_SupremeStorms_CoT_patch.esp=1
ELFXEnhancer.esp=1
Field Alchemy.esp=1
RealisticNeedsandDiseases.esp=1
RND_Dawnguard-Patch.esp=1
RND_HearthFires-Patch.esp=1
RND_Dragonborn-Patch.esp=1
RND_DrinkingFountains-Patch.esp=1
RND_Requiem-Patch.esp=1
RND_USKP-Patch.esp=1
Dual Wield Parrying_SKSE.esp=1
The Dance of Death - Ultimate Edition.esp=1
Cooking Expanded - RND Support.esp=1
RND_RWLReduced-Patch.esp=1
SPTConsistentOlderPeople.esp=1
moveitLWT.esp=1
Bashed Patch, 0.esp=1
AOS_CTD_Fix.esp=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [BOSS](http://boss-developers.github.io/) to automatically sort your mods and read its warnings and errors to determine if you need to do anything special to make your setup work.

Comment: i already mentioned that my list is sorted by Boss. There are no warnings or errors in boss log. Wrye bash gives me no errors either. TES5edit states: Requiem - Moonpath Patch.esp" requires master "moonpath_questdata.esp" to be loaded before it.
same thing for GDO

Comment: @Dictator if a required master is missing the game will crash as soon as you start it. Does your game crash?

Comment: No it doesn't crash. The masters are there but for some reason Boss doesn't order them correctly. TES5Edit sees that and gives the error. My question is should i move the master or the patch? The author of Requiem states that requiem along with requiem patches should go at the bottom. I just wanna make sure.

Comment: to be more precise, if i manually move the masters before the requiem patches then all works fine and TES5edit gives no errors. The thing is, that requiem is sorted by boss at the middle of the list while the author of Requiem says it should go at the bottom. I'm just trying to avoid conflicts

Comment: @Dictator in that case my advice continues to be "stick with what the BOSS ordered". Most recommendations to put the mod at the very bottom are made by egomaniacs or lazy people.

Comment: Thanx for the replies and if u see anything else in my list that u think would create problems in terms of stability/compatibility by all means tell me.

Answer (score 1):

@kotekzot is not entirely right. It depends on what experience you want to achieve with your mods. Requiem makes a large number of changes to lots of stuff. Many will get over-written if you follow BOSS's load order, you may not want this. People misunderstand what BOSS accomplishes. The way the master-list is organized you will rarely experience a CTD after using BOSS, but it is not the universally "correct" load order, just a safe practice order. However unless you know what you are doing I would recommend following BOSS's order.

In the case though BOSS has sorted two incorrectly that I know of. Requiem - Moonpath Patch.esp should load after moonpath_questdata.esp and Requiem - Guard Dialogue Overhaul Patch.esp after Guard Dialogue Overhaul.esp. See the Nexsus pages for those patches.

Also if it interested you there is a patch for Dance of Death on the Nexus that fixes it so that Requiem's perk restrictions on kill-moves also applies to the moves DOD adds.

Comment: thanx for the reply. So maybe in the case of Requiem Boss isn't to be trusted? Afterall Requiem is the core of my list. I added all the other mods to further enhance Requiem with minimum to zero conflicts( been reading endless pages of mod suggestions in forums). I think i ll go with the author and his recommendation of overriding boss and manually moving Requiem and Requiem mods at the bottom.